# How to Setup a Private Network in Hyperledger Besu?

Tags: hyperledger, besu

I am looking for steps to configure hyperledger besu client for a private network of say 5 nodes.

Answer (score 2):

What consensus type do you want to use ?
You can find a tutorial to create a private network depending on the consensus:

- https://besu.hyperledger.org/en/stable/Tutorials/Private-Network/Create-IBFT-Network/
- https://besu.hyperledger.org/en/stable/Tutorials/Private-Network/Create-Private-Network/
- https://besu.hyperledger.org/en/stable/Tutorials/Private-Network/Create-Private-Clique-Network/